# custom rewrite rule help! Custom rewrite rules not applying to custom post type

Tags: php, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to setup custom rewrite rules and display custom fields the url. I have set it up correctly for the post type 'things to do' with the custom field is displaying. However, when I try adding 'venues' in the else if statement the permalink isn't being updated. I have added print_r($placeslug2); to see if the correct field is being retrieved and it's showing up on the page.

I'm not sure why it's not returning the correct permalink structure for venues.

Can anyone help please?

```
add_action('init', 'wpq_add_rewrite_rules');
add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpq_permalinks', 10, 3);

function wpq_add_rewrite_rules()
{
// Register custom rewrite rules

global $wp_rewrite;

$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%place%', '([^/]+)', 'place=');
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%venue%', '([^/]+)', 'venue=');
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%things_to_do%', '([^/]+)', 'things_to_do=');

$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('things_to_do', '/%place%/%venue%/%things_to_do%', false);
}


function wpq_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename)
{

$no_data = 'no-data';

$post_id = $post->ID;

if($post->post_type != 'things_to_do' && $post->post_type != 'venues'  || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
return $permalink;

if($post->post_type == 'things_to_do') {

    $venue = get_post_meta($post_id, 'venue', true);
    $postvenue = get_post($venue);

    $place = get_post_meta($venue, 'place', true);    
    $postplace = get_post($place);

    $venueslug = $postvenue->post_name;
    $placeslug = $postplace->post_name;

    if(!$data)
    $data = $no_data;

    $permalink = str_replace('%place%', $placeslug, $permalink);
    $permalink = str_replace('%venue%', $venueslug, $permalink);

return $permalink;

}


elseif($post->post_type == 'venues') {

    $place2 = get_post_meta($post_id, 'place', true); 

    $postplace2 = get_post($place2);
    $placeslug2 = $postplace2->post_name;

    print_r($placeslug2);

    if(!$data)
    $data = $no_data;

    $permalink = str_replace('%place%', $placeslug2, $permalink);

    return $permalink;  
}

}
```

Comment: What does the permastruct for that post type look like? I only see the one you added for `things_to_do`.

Comment: Do i need to create another pemastructure for venues post type? Can't I run them both off the one i have?